# How to join two tables and repeat the distinct date Showing the date for all records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I hope someone would help me with:
I have first table WorkerT:

| WorkerID | WorkerName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

and Second Table AttendanceT:

| WorkerID | LastDayMonth | Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31/10/23 | V |
| 2 | 31/10/23 | V |
| 1 | 30/09/23 | V |
| 3 | 31/08/23 | V |

I want a query after joining both tables to have for each worker all the distinct LastDayMonth:

| WorkerID | WorkerName | LastDayMonth | Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 31/10/23 | V |
| 1 | a | 30/09/23 | V |
| 1 | a | 31/08/23 |  |
| 2 | b | 31/10/23 | V |
| 2 | b | 30/09/23 |  |
| 2 | b | 31/08/23 |  |
| 3 | c | 31/10/23 |  |
| 3 | c | 30/09/23 |  |
| 3 | c | 31/08/23 | V |

thanks.

I tried this but it does'nt make distinct date value:

```
SELECT WorkerT.WorkerID, WorkerT.WorkerName, AttendanceT.LastDayMonth, AttendanceT.Attendance
FROM WorkerT, AttendanceT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning records for data that does not exist is a common topic. This requires a dataset of all possible employee/date pairs. This dataset can be generated with Cartesian product query then that query used in subsequent queries. Be aware this sort of query can perform slowly with large data source.

AllEmpDates

```
SELECT DISTINCT WorkerT.WorkerID, WorkerT.WorkerName, AttendanceT.LastDayMonth FROM WorkerT, AttendanceT;
```

All-in-one SQL with nested Cartesian product query:

```
SELECT AllEmpDates.*, AttendanceT.Attendance
FROM AttendanceT 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT WorkerT.WorkerID, WorkerName, LastDayMonth
            FROM WorkerT, AttendanceT ) AS AllEmpDates 
ON (AttendanceT.LastDayMonth = AllEmpDates.LastDayMonth) AND (AttendanceT.WorkerID = AllEmpDates.WorkerID)
ORDER BY AllEmpDates.WorkerID, AllEmpDates.LastDayMonth DESC;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, concern slowly performance if I am creating a monthly form, is it faster to base form record source on the Cartesian query or to use the dlookup function to give the attendace value as unbound control?

Comment: Do you mean you would show attendance for all workers for only one LastDayMonth date? That is possible - form or report bound to WorkerT:  `=DLookup("Attendance", "AttendanceT", "WorkerID=" & [WorkerID] & " AND LastDayMonth=#" & [tbxDate] & "#")`. Domain aggregate functions have their own performance issue in queries and textboxes. You can compare.

Answer (score 2):

We can first get all unique LastDayMonth values, cross them with all Workers giving a list of unique worker-lastMonthEnd combinations. We then `LEFT JOIN` this with AttendanceT to report attendance if exists; still returning a row if the attendance is not there (but Attendance will be NULL for those cases).

```
select 

    AllWrkMth.WorkerID
  , AllWrkMth.WorkerName
  , AllWrkMth.LastDayMonth
  , A.Attendance
from (
      select DISTINCT WorkerT.WorkerID, WorkerName, LastDayMonth from WorkerT, AttendanceT
     ) AllWrkMth

     left join
     AttendanceT A
     on A.LastDayMonth=AllWrkMth.LastDayMonth
     and a.WorkerId=AllWrkMth.WorkerID
order by 
  AllWrkMth.WorkerID
 , AllWrkMth.LastDayMonth desc
;
```

UPDATE: applied the simplification suggested by @June7: thanks!

Comment: I did not see your answer before posting mine. This all-in-one statement works.

Comment: Although, can simplify nested SQL `... from (select DISTINCT WorkerT.WorkerID, WorkerName, LastDayMonth from WorkerT, AttendanceT) AllWrkMth
left join ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query, this will return the latest date on the list for each employ

```
SELECT W.WorkerID,W.WorkerName,A.LastDayMonth,A.Attendance
FROM Worker as W
INNER JOIN AttendanceT as A on A.WorkerID=W.WorkerID
WHERE A.LastDayMonth in (SELECT TOP 1 AT.LastDayMonth 
                   FROM AttendanceT as AT 
                   WHERE AT.WorkerID=W.WorkerID 
                   Order by AT.LastDayMonth DESC)
```

Comment: OP does not want latest data for each employee, they want all dates associated with each employee and showing if employee was or was not in attendance each date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT WorkerT.WorkerID, WorkerT.WorkerName, sub.LastDayMonth 
FROM WorkerT
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT WorkerID, LastDayMonth FROM AttendanceT) sub ON WorkerT.WorkerID = sub.WorkerID
```

[proof of concept using programiz.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnS7q.png)

Comment: Output in proof is not what OP wants.

Comment: An image is not appropriate for demonstration of SQL. Explore tool like http://sqlfiddle.com/. Post link in answer to your solution.

Comment: Image does not even show output of posted SQL. The quey does not produce what OP wants.